# “Is there a way to get sequence of most consecutive alphabet?”

Tags: string, python-3.6, sequence

I am working on a python problem which has a string such as “aaabbcc” and a number n (integer). 
I have to display a sequence of any Alphabetic character that appears exactly n times.

I have tried the code

```
import collections
str1 = 'aaabbcc'
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for c in str1:
    d[c] += 1

for c in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True):
  if d[c] > 1:
      print(c, d[c])
```

But I am getting output as

```
a 3
b 2
c 2
```

I am expecting output as the integer input `3` is input is taken, from user.

```
integer= 3 
sequence= aaa
```

Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)-based approach:

```
from itertools import groupby

str1 = 'aaabbcc'
n = 3

for key, group in groupby(str1):
    if len(tuple(group)) == n:
        print(f'integer: {n} sequence: {n*key}')
```

withot a `key` `groupby` will group the sequence by identity - i.e. every time the letter in `str1` changes it will yield that letter and its occurrences.

Comment: I got it! had a collection based approach in mind but not iterative. can I also take a string and integer input from the user?

Comment: yes I did but no luck, the console is taking the inputs but not returning the output

Comment: `str1 = input('str1? '); n = int(input('n? '))` (or sth similar) does not work? then you may have to post it as a new question; it will be difficult to handle that down here in the comments.

Comment: Yes got it! forgot to put ```int``` in front of n

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex based approach which seems to work:

```
input = "ddaaabbbbbbbbccceeeeeee"
n = 3
for match in re.finditer(r'(.)(?!\1)(.)\2{' + str(n-1) + r'}(?!\2)', input):
print(match.group(0)[1:])

aaa
ccc
```

The regex pattern being used in the exact example above is this:

```
(.)(?!\1)(.)\2{2}(?!\2)
```

This says to:

```
(.)     match and capture any single character
(?!\1)  assert that the next character is different
(.)     then match and capture that next character
\2{2}   which is then followed by that same character exactly twice (total of 3)
(?!\2)  after three instances, the character that follows is NOT the same
```

Answer (score 0):

a loop-based approach (that should be pretty straight-forward):

```
str1 = 'aaabbcc'
n = 3

count = 1
last = None
for char in str1:
    if last == char:
        count += 1
    else:
        if count == n:
            print(f'integer: {n} sequence: {n*last}')
        last = char
        count = 1
if count == n:
    print(f'integer: {n} sequence: {n*last}')
```

the last if statement is there to print a solution if one was found including the last character of `str1`.

Comment: I am getting an output as ```integer= 3 sequence=bbb``` instead of ```sequence=aaa```

Comment: my input is: "aaabbcc"

Comment: ooops! that was a bug: i was printing `char` instead of `last`. fixed it.